# Can not inflate Custom Views from XML Layout in Android

Tags: android-layout

I have made a CustomView and a xml layout for it in order to be able to inflate it for my Activity but when running the Activity is never getting any layout and instead i get an error message indicating  error parsing the xml file layout

This is my Activity 
    package com.example.myproject;

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.view.Menu;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.custom_view_layout); 
 }

@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }


    and this is my custom view


 package com.example.myproject;

import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
  import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.view.View;

 public class CustomView extends View {

public CustomView(Context context) {
     super(context);

 }

  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

      canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
}
  }


       and this is the layout i made for it


 <com.exemple.myproject.CustomView 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >
</com.exemple.myproject.CustomView>

  and this is my Android Manifest

   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.myproject"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myproject.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I have looked at Google and specially here at stackoverflow and found some similar errors and solutions like letting my Activity extend FragmentActivity instead of of normal Activity but that did not work with me and also a meta-data tag was suggested in the manifest but really i did not know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

```
com.exemple.myproject.CustomView
```

maybe 'example' instead of 'exemple'.

And add `xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` if you have custom params for the view.

Comment: There is no error with 'exemple' because i wrote it not 'example' in the the package name

Comment: And please can you clear me the attribute xmlns:youapp ? and by the wayn it did not work with me

Comment: be attentive, in your snippet of code '<com.exemple.myproject.CustomView 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"'

Comment: What do you mean exacltly ? what kind of mistakes i should specially avoid ?

Comment: 'xmlns:youapp ...' should work, it gives you ability to create custom parameters for your view, e.g. add diameter or radius: yourapp:diameter="1.0" or yourapp:radius="1.0".

Comment: Ok but i have no parameters within this custom view it is basically its only changing the background color to green and i like to show it via the layout like i said

Comment: ok, it isn't necessary for you, but you have different name of package, your view is located in 'com.example.myproject' but you wrote  in xml 'com.exemple.myproject.CustomView'

Comment: Ok you were right i changed the package name and fixed it now but nothing new !! the same error

Comment: I don't see 'super.onDraw(canvas);' and why is android:orientation="vertical"? please, read this article http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html